# Is there a way to do a rails "yield/content_for" in GRAILS?

Tags: grails

In rails, I'm used to use the `yield/content_for` to site mesh. (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-content_for)

I can't find in Grails documentation a way to do this... Could you help me?

**EDIT**

Here is the situation:

I have a layout containing this:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <g:render template="/layouts/header"/>
            </div>
            <g:render template="/layouts/menu"/>
            <div id="container-homepage">
                <g:layoutBody/>
                <div id="subfooter">
                    <div id="content">
                        <div id="left">
                            <div id="logo_sub_header"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="right"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And I want to be able to add a html snippet (search tool bar for example) juste above the `container-homepage` div. A partial could do the trick.. if this search tool bar was always the same. The thing here is that this search bar depends on the page i'm visiting.

I could also just change the position of the container-homepage div to put it directly into the view, and not the layout, but then i'll have to to it in ALL the views, and that's not DRY.

Any ideas?
Regards,

Comment: I think content blocks would work for you. See my reply below. Fabrizio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two solutions:

the g:render tag is the best option if your content block will not change based on a custom page.

Anyway I would take a look ah this link 
http://grails.org/Content+Blocks

because g:pageProperty it is the most elegant and flexible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [g:render](http://www.grails.org/Tag+-+render) tag is what you're looking for?  It allows you to render a template anywhere within your view (including in other templates).  You can also pass in a model for the template to use.

Note the section at the bottom of that page on naming conventions -- template view gsp filenames should begin with an underscore (though that underscore is not supplied in the render tag).  There's mos def a way to override this, but things work automagically if you put the underscore there.

Comment: I edited my question to explain a partial would not do the trick.